# Cannot execute the else statement it gives out an error

Tags: c++, if-statement

**
I wanted to print each integer (n) between b and c such that if n>9 else statement executes and prints out each integers in the form of even or odd.The if statements executes if the following condition of the variables of c and b are true.So there is no problem if i input c and b both <9.
**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {

      int b;
      int c;

      string x[9] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

      cin >> c;
      cin >> b;

      for (int r=0 ; c <= b ; c+1) {

           c=c+1+r;

           if (1<= c <= 9) {
                 cout << x[c-2] << endl;
           } else {
                 if (c%2  != 0) {              
                     cout << "odd" << endl;
                 } else {
                     cout << "even" << endl;
                 }
           }
       c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x[c-2]` will be out-of-range when `c = 1`.

Comment: `c+1` in your for loop won't do what you want. Your for loop is unusual and almost certainly wrong  (`r` never changes, for example) so you should revisit this code.

Comment: @jarmod ya its wrong and i know i just wanted to know whats problem with my else statement which i got answer for i didn't ask anyone to correct my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `1<= c <= 9` won't work as you expected.

`1<= c <= 9` is treated as `(1 <= c) <= 9`.

`1 <= c` here will be treated as `0` or `1`, so the condition `(1 <= c) <= 9` will always be true.

You should use `1 <= c && c <= 9` instead.

Comment: it gave an error  - expected primary expression before '<='  token

Comment: @INFINITY3609 [I don't get that error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/12SSkfQzCs7OVd42). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want some help.

Comment: Thanks MikeCAT sorry it was a typing error due to which i was getting that error